# Why the blog data is not passing to the database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am working on a simple CRUD project with the MERN stack.
In the project, I'm trying to update the blog for the particular article. But it's not updating the blogs collection.

**index.js**

```
app.put('/updateblog/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const newBlogTitle = req.body.newBlogTitle;
    const newBlogAuthor = req.body.newBlogAuthor;
    const newBlogContent = req.body.newBlogContent;
    const {id} = req.params;
    console.log(id);
    
    try{
        await Blog.findByIdAndUpdate( id , (err , updatedBlog) => {
            updatedBlog.blogTitle = newBlogTitle;
            updatedBlog.blogAuthor = newBlogAuthor;
            updatedBlog.blogContent = newBlogContent;
            updatedBlog.save();
            res.send("updated");
        })
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }

})
```

**Edit.js**
Using aixos to get the post all the `post` details:

```
      useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/blogList" )
        .then((response) => {
            setContent(response.data)
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        
        }, [])
```

Update the data using `put` method

```
    const log = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (editorRef.current) {
            console.log(editorRef.current.getContent());
            //setContent(editorRef.current.getContent());
            setNewBlogContent(editorRef.current.getContent())
        }
        try{
            await axios.put('http://localhost:5000/updateblog/' + id, {
                newBlogTitle,
                newBlogAuthor,
                newBlogContent
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log('Blog successfully updated')
                navigate('/blog')
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
              })
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

     if (!content) return null;
```

Blog Section

```
<div className="container">
    <div className='fw-bold text-center mt-3 fs-1'>Edit Content</div>
    <form onSubmit={log}>
    {content.filter(cnt => cnt._id === id )
    .map(cDetails => (
        <div key={cDetails._id}>
            <div className='container'> 
                <div className='container bg-light mt-3 p-3'>
                    <label for="Blogtitle" className="form-label mt-3">Blog Title</label>
                    <input type='text' name="title" id="Blogtitle" className=' mt-3 form-control' required
                    value={newBlogTitle} 
                    onChange={e => setNewBlogTitle(e.target.value)} placeholder={cDetails.blogTitle} />
                    <label for="BlogAuthor" className="form-label mt-3">Blog Title</label>
                    <input type='text' name="authorName" id="BlogAuthor" className=' mt-3 form-control' 
                    value={newBlogAuthor} required
                    onChange={e => setNewBlogAuthor(e.target.value)} placeholder={cDetails.blogAuthor} />
                    {/* <div className=' bg-light mt-3 text-muted fst-italic text-end px-4'>  - By {cDetails.blogAuthor}</div> */}
                    
                </div>
                <div className='container mt-5'>
                    <Editor
                    onInit={(evt, editor) => {
                    setNewBlogContent(editor.getContent({format: 'html'}));
                    }}
                    initialValue={cDetails.blogContent}
                    onEditorChange={(newValue, editor) => {
                    setNewBlogContent(editor.getContent({format: 'html'}));
                    }}
                />
                </div> 

            </div>
        </div>
    ) )
    }
    <button type='submit' className="btn btn-primary mt-3 mx-4" >Update editor content</button>   

    </form>
</div>
    </div>
```

**The content state example output,**

[image: cide]

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken to verify/validate that your database isn't updating as expected? Is the frontend making the PUT request correctly? Is the backend receiving it? Are there any errors in your backend?

Comment: The backend error shows **undefined**. I think there should be the error. I don't no to clarify.

Comment: Can you tell us something about request response?

Comment: I see, so there is an error in the backend. Can you add the entirety of that error into your question? I see your PUT endpoint doesn't do much processing, and you share the `Blog.findByIdAndUpdate` function?